# Targeting a single HTML element with CSS in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to re-style the page title (h1) on just one particular page (node) of a Drupal 7 site. What is the best way of targeting a single HTML element with CSS on a particular page?

Obviously, I want the page title on all other pages to be unaffected.

I am using a sub-theme of Bartik, if it make any difference.

Comment: Have using an ID on that `h1`?

Comment: Nothing that would single it out from other nodes, I don't think.

Comment: Drupal adds loads of classes to the body to identify each page, check there. e.g. for the front page you could use `body.front h1 {...`

Answer (score 0):

Normally in most of the themes classes are added to the body tag. Unless you are using themes like [mothership](http://drupal.org/project/mothership) where you can force it to remove such classes, these can be pretty much handy. Even mothership provides a settings to enable/disable populating of body tag with such classes.

Use inspect element in chrome or Firebug in Firefox or Developer Toolbar in IE to look for the class that represent something like `<content_type>-<entity-type>-<id>` in `<body>` tag in the page you want to theme. For example `page-node-12`

An example output for omega theme is as below

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in page-node page-node- page-node-8 node-type-page context-page admin-menu coffee-processed omega-mediaqueries-processed alpha-debug-processed responsive-layout-wide">
```

An example body tag output for Bartic theme,

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-33 node-type-team-member admin-menu coffee-processed">
```

then find the specific selector for your node title, which would be like say `#page-title` or in case it doesn't have an id figure out some rule to select it so its unique in a page. For example `.page h1.title`

Now you can use,

```
body.page-node-12 #page-title {
  /* your css rule */
}
```

or

```
body.page-node-12 .page h1.title {
  /* your css rule */
}
```